# How to Serialize/Deserialize table using schema in lua

Tags: serialization, lua, schema, deserialization, lua-table

I have the following table:

```
local obj = {
    firstname = "John",
    lastname  = "Bush",
    age = 22,
    height = 186,
    friends = {
        { firstname = "Paul", lastname = "Graham", age = 20, height = 178 },
        { firstname = "Gianou", lastname = "Kwnstantina", age = 25, height = 172 }
    },
    bodies = { 4, 3, 10 }
}
```

and I want to transform it to this: (when inserting to database)

```
local tuple = {
    'John', 'Bush', 22, 186, { { 'Paul', 'Graham', 20, 178 }, { 'Gianou', 'Kwnstantina', 25, 172 } }, { 4, 3, 10 }
}
```

which I managed to generate using:

```
function encode(schema, data)
    local array = {}

    function rec(arr, schema, d)

        for i, field in ipairs(schema) do

            arr[i] = {}
            if field.type == "array" and type(field.items) == "table" then

                for it, piece in ipairs(d[field.name]) do
                    arr[i][it] = {}
                    rec(arr[i][it], field.items, piece)
                end

            else

                arr[i] = d[field.name]

            end

        end
    end

    rec(array, schema, data)

    return array
end
```

My problem is that I want to reconstruct that data to the initial form when I retrieve it. I found some tools that can do this in other languages but the problem is that they transform the data to binary, I just want that array.

To be able to reconstruct I need something like a schema:

```
local schema = {
    { name = "firstname", type = "string" },
    { name = "lastname", type = "string" },
    { name = "age", type = "int" },
    { name = "height", type = "int" },
    { name = "friends", type = "array", items = {
        { name = "firstname", type = "string" },
        { name = "lastname", type = "string" },
        { name = "age", type = "int" },
        { name = "height", type = "int" }
    }},
    { name = "bodies", type = "array", items = "int"}    
}
```

I found that it's pretty easy to encode it just by retrieving the values but being able to validate and decode it seems pretty hard, is there a concept (name) for this operation in computer science, or a library that I can study (it needs to use a schema)?
I need a keyword to google...

Thank you!

EDIT: Just reversing the encode I found a simple way to decode.

```
function decode(schema, data)
    local obj = {}

    function rec(object, sch, d)
        for i, field in ipairs(sch) do

            if field.type == "array" and type(field.items) == "table" then
                object[field.name] = {}

                for it, piece in ipairs(d[i]) do

                    object[field.name][it] = {}

                    rec(object[field.name][it], field.items, piece)
                end

            else
                object[field.name] = d[i]
            end


        end
    end

    rec(obj, schema, data)

    return obj
end
```

I would still love suggestions on the code and where can I found more info on this type of info.

present version: https://pastebin.com/Ub4vZ0GU